# Average across many files on matlab

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if I can get help with this. I have many .mat files with an array in each and I want to average each cell individually (average all (1,1)s, all (1,2)s, ... (2,1)s etc.) and store them.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how your data is organised, but you can do something like this:

```
% Assume you know the size of the arrays and that the variables r and c
% hold the numbers of rows and columns respectively.

xTotals = zeros(r, c);
xCount = 0;


% for each file: assume the data is loaded into a variable called x, which is
% r rows by c columns
for ...
  xTotals = xTotals + x;
  xCount = xCount + 1;
end

xAvg = xTotals / xCount;
```

And `xAvg` will contain the average for each array cell.  Note that you probably know `xCount` without having to count each time you go round the loop, but it depends on where you are getting your data.  Hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: Replace `/` with `./`, for element-wise division.

Comment: if `xCount` is a scalar it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Pursuit As natan said, I purposely left it like that as it is just a scalar.